# Java Script. How to choose any few items of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm designing a quiz motivator, i.e. if a user inputs any number of correct answers he's gonna get rewarded with a "star" or smth. The array in a pseudo code below represents a range of correct answers to choose from:

```js
var rightAnswers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

if (rightAnswers.chooseAny(3)) {user gets a star}
else if (rightAnswers.chooseAny(6)) {user gets 2 stars}
else if (rightAnswers.chooseAny(9) {user gets 3 stars}
```

I haven't found anything that would work instead of my pseudo "chooseAny()", any ideas, please?

Comment: What's the expected output from `.chooseAny(N)`?

Comment: Where's the user input?

Comment: the name chooseAny is cryptic , explain further on your idea ?

Comment: Expected output is just a ranking - if any 3 answers of 15 in total are correct user gets 1 badge, if 6 are correct - 2 badges and so on. Each input is done through the inputField.value and matched with individual array of correct answers for each question

Comment: name chooseAny is not a part of the code it's just an idea of how i want it

Comment: So `rightAnswers` array elements are all boolean, true for right answer and false for wrong one?

Comment: Exactly! All I need is to be able to choose any specific number of them, not all of them at once

Comment: You should check in reverse order, because even if there is 9 correct answers, you will find out at first if that there are 3 correct answer, and you won't check if there is more. I would count correct answers or even count them as you add true/false to array, and then compare that number, so you don't need to count them 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't looking for a `chooseAny` function; I think what you're really asking for is a way to count how many answers were correct given a set of `answers` and an `answerKey`.

The `getTotalCorrect` function below does that for you using a for-loop and identity comparison, and you can use `getStars` to determine how many stars should be awarded based on the score that is returned.

```js
var answerKey = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

function getTotalCorrect (answers, answerKey) {
  for (var correct = 0, i = 0; i < answerKey.length; i++) {
    if (answers[i] === answerKey[i]) correct++
  }
  return correct
}

function getStars (totalCorrect) {
   return (totalCorrect / 3) | 0
}

var totalCorrect = getTotalCorrect(['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e'], answerKey)
console.log(totalCorrect) //=> 3

var stars = getStars(totalCorrect)
console.log(stars) //=> 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that i guess i can make sense of!